Laravel optional route params not working
I have to setup a multi-language  application with Laravel 11, this is the first time that I use multi-language feature in laravel, I will not use any package, I will set it manually, so I prepared the web.php file like this :
Route::group(['middleware' => ['setLocale']], function () {
    Route::get('/products/{slug}', [ProductController::class, 'fetchProduct']);
});
Route::group(['middleware' => ['setLocale'], 'prefix' => '{locale?}', 'where' => ['locale' => 'en|fr|de|jp']], function () {
    Route::get('/', LandingController::class);
    Route::get('/products/{slug}', [ProductController::class, 'fetchProduct']);
});

When I access '/products/fr/exemple-product' it works but when I tried to access to the default route like this: '/products/exemple-product' it doesn't work and handles an error:
Too few arguments to function App\\Http\\Controllers\\Front\\ProductController::fetchProduct(), 1 passed in C:\\...\\ControllerDispatcher.php on line 46 and exactly 2 expected 
this is the definition of the fetchProduct method :
public function fetchProduct($locale = null, $slug) {dd($slug);}

Even if I set $locale to null, it doesn't work.

fetchProduct($locale = null, $slug) - If define your arguments like this, then the first parameter is actually not optional anymore as you still need to pass the second argument. You should swap the parameters from place, e.g. fetchProduct($slug, $locale = null)

@DarkBee when I swap like this I get the slug value not corrected , It takes the value of the locale

The point is that you cannot have a optional parameter followed by a required parameter.  Switching them in the function only will indeed take the wrong value.  The easiest solution would be having a separate route with and without the locale parameter. But even better, there are packages available that will handle a optional locale parameter. https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization

@GertB. I have already create separate route with and without the locale parameter. please check the question again! and I don't want to use packages

You have a separate route, but the locale parameter is optional in the other route, so that matches too.  I wonder why you don't want to use packages.

@GertB. I want to simplify the logic, that's why

You cannot have an optional parameter before a required one, i.e. you cannot have ($lang = null, $slug).
Swapping them is a no-go since laravel, in this case, injects the parameters based on the order they appear in the url.
A solution could be to create a separate function for the route with different parameters. An even better solution is to use a package such as mcamara/laravel-localization to handle this requirement for you.
routes.php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['setLocale']], function () {
    Route::get('/products/{slug}', [ProductController::class, 'fetchProductWithoutLocale']);
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['setLocale'], 'prefix' => '{locale?}', 'where' => ['locale' => 'en|fr|de|jp']], function () {
    Route::get('/products/{slug}', [ProductController::class, 'fetchProduct']);
});

Controller.php
public function fetchProduct($locale, $slug) {dd($slug);}

public function fetchProductWithoutLocale($slug) {
  $locale = config('app.fallback_locale'); // or your logic to retrieve a default

  return $this->fetchProduct($locale, $slug);
}


The positioning of the parameters in the method fetchProduct is the problem on there. You cannot have an optional parameter before a required one. When the method is called, it will assume the first parameter is also required thereby assigning the value passed to the $locale variable and requiring you to provide a second argument for $slug. The positioning of the parameters should be swapped as below to rectify this.
public function fetchProduct($slug, $locale = null){}


This was already addressed in the comments and rectified by OP
